# redirecting from /settings/ to settings.php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect from *localhost/myproject/setting/* to *localhost/myproject/settings.php*  using the `.htacess` file.

I used the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^setting/$  settings.php [L]
```

But, it first takes me to *localhost/myproject/setting/*, then it runs *settings.php* file. I don't want this. [There is no folder with name of "setting" in my root!]

How I can fix my problem?

Comment: What do you mean with first calling? Your browser have to first calling /settings/ because it needs the the information about redirection.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right you want to redirect from anything starting with
`localhost/myproject/setting/` like `localhost/myproject/setting/anything.php` to `localhost/myproject/settings.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  "^/setting/(.*)$" "settings.php" [L]
```

if you want to pass GET variables sent to the `/seting/` to be passed through to  `settings.php` use this

```
RewriteRule  "^/setting/(.*)$" "settings.php$1" [L, PT]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 

Another problem still exists for me. When using localhost/myproject/settings.php, all css, image and AJAX codes runs correctly. But when using  localhost/myproject/setting/,  images  are not showing and ajax codes are not working, after rewriting by htacess.
Is there a simple solution for that too ?

Comment: Open a new question and be a bit more verbose, post a bit of code that is not working and so on. I promise to help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when your rule matches, it does inside the `/setting/` folder. Then, it tries to internally rewrite it to `settings.php` **in the current folder** (because you're using a relative path). Solution: use a `RewriteBase` instead of playing with relative/absolute paths

Here is how your `/myproject/.htaccess` file should look like

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

# RewriteBase path (/myproject/) is always added in front of relative path -> /myproject/settings.php
RewriteRule ^setting/$  settings.php [L]
```